# Tokenizing a String is not happening within double quotes in springbatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, tokenize

> Currently - {operation=, sharedFl=, listName="TSTLST1207      Y   U,
> userId=QA10ADMINRT02, rowType=LIST_INFO:, masterAccount=NAT,
> listDescription=}
>
> Expected - {operation=U, sharedFl=Y, listName="TSTLST1207,
> userId=QA10ADMINRT02, rowType=LIST_INFO:, masterAccount=NAT,
> listDescription=}

listName is just "TSTLST1207 , since it has double quotes, it is not tokenizing any further columns. I should get ***listName="TSTLST1207*** but now i see ***listName="TSTLST1207      Y   U***

Y and U are values of different columns

These columns are read from textfile

```
private LineTokenizer createFlatFileLineTokenizer() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setDelimiter("\t");
    tokenizer.setNames(FIELDS);
        return tokenizer;
   }
```

Comment: ... and you expect this to be enough for us to understand what's going on? we have no idea what your input is, let's start with that.

Comment: Please add more info to your questions, what are you trying to achieve and how, and what seems to be not working - the clearer the question is the better the chances for a constructive answer